# How to split url and call a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to convert my all wordpress theme link to be ajax enable. So, I am using this code

```
siteUrl = "http://" + top.location.host.toString(),
    url = ''; 

$(document).delegate("a[href^='" + siteUrl + "']:not([href*=/wp-admin/]):not([href*=/wp-login.php]):not([href$=/feed/])", "click", function() {
    var pathname = this.pathname; 
    return false;
});
```

Now, I want if this var pathname is like `/ebook/some-ebook` then I want to call the `post_load()` function and if it is like `/ebook` then I want to call the `post_archive()` javascript function.

`ebook` is a `post-type` and `some-ebook` is `%postname%`.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand half of what you're asking...but it sounds like you just want to [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `pathname` into its relevant pieces.

In that case, you can do something like the following:

```
var pathPieces  = pathname.split('/', 3),
    archiveName = pathPieces[1],
    postName    = pathPieces[2];
```

At that point, you can do whatever you want with those path pieces. For example:

```
if ( archiveName === 'ebook' ) {
    post_archive();
}
```